# Scripting a clamscan summary that adds multiple "Infected files" outputs together

Tags: bash, scripting

I want a simple way to add 2 numbers taken from a text file. Details below:

Daily, I run clamscan against my /home/ folder, which generates a simple log along the lines of this:

```
Scanning 851M in /home/.

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2021:11:27 06:25:02
End Date:   2021:11:27 06:25:02
```

Weekly, I scan both my /home/ folder and an external drive, so I get twice as much in the log:

```
Scanning 851M in /home/.

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Time: 0.000 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2021:11:28 06:25:02
End Date:   2021:11:28 06:25:02

Scanning 2.8T in /mnt/ext/.

----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 0
Time: 0.005 sec (0 m 0 s)
Start Date: 2021:11:28 06:26:30
End Date:   2021:11:28 06:26:30
```

I don't email the log to myself, I just have a bash script that sends an email that (for the daily scan) reads the number that comes after "Infected files:" and says either "No infected files found" or "Infected files found, check log." (And, to be honest, once I'm 100% comfortable that it all works the way I want it to, I'll skip the "No infected files found" email.) The problem is, I don't know how to make that work for the weekly scan of multiple folders, because the summary I get doesn't combine those numbers.

I'd like the script to find both lines that start "Infected files:", get the numbers that follow, and add them. I guess the ideal solution use a loop in case I ever need to scan more than two folders. I've taken a couple of stabs at it with grep and cut, but I'm just not experienced enough a coder to make it all work.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bash script will print out the sum of infected files:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(sed -n 's/^Infected files://p' logfile)
echo $((${n//$'\n'/+}))
```

or a one-liner:

```
echo $(( $(sed -n 's/^Infected files: \(.*\)/+\1/p' logfile) ))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll take that for a spin!

Comment: It took much longer to get around to testing this than I expected, but it seems to work perfectly! For what it's worth, sed is utterly opaque to me, so I'd love if you could break down the way it works.